# Pandas keep the most complete rows

Tags: python, pandas, missing-data, pandas-groupby

Lets say I have a dataframe that has a lot of missing data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a','a','b','b','b','c','d','e','e','e'],
                   'q1': [1,1,np.NaN,np.NaN,0,np.NaN,1,np.NaN,1,0],
                   'q2': ['low',np.NaN,np.NaN,'high','low','high','high',np.NaN,np.NaN,'low'],
                   'q3': [np.NaN,1,np.NaN,1,0,0,1,0,np.NaN,np.NaN]
                   })
```

Which looks like this:

```
  id   q1    q2   q3
0  a  1.0   low  NaN
1  a  1.0   NaN  1.0
2  b  NaN   NaN  NaN
3  b  NaN  high  1.0
4  b  0.0   low  0.0
5  c  NaN  high  0.0
6  d  1.0  high  1.0
7  e  NaN   NaN  0.0
8  e  1.0   NaN  NaN
9  e  0.0   low  NaN
```

I want to create a new dataframe that contains only 1 row from each `id`, but that row is the most complete (least instances of NaN), but if theyre equally complete, then the first occurrence in the current sort order

Ideal output is a new dataframe:

```
  id   q1    q2   q3
0  a  1.0   low  NaN
1  b  0.0   low  0.0
2  c  NaN  high  0.0
3  d  1.0  high  1.0
4  e  0.0   low  NaN
```

I can count the number of NA in each row using `df.isnull().sum(axis=1)` but I'm not sure how to use that to then select out the row with the smallest sum, especially if there are more than 2 entries for an `id`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a surrogate column to sort based on counts and filter with a `groupby`.

```
df = df.assign(count=df.isnull().sum(1))\
       .sort_values(['id', 'count'])\
       .groupby('id', as_index=0).head(1)\
       .drop('count', 1)

print(df)
  id   q1    q2   q3
0  a  1.0   low  NaN
4  b  0.0   low  0.0
5  c  NaN  high  0.0
6  d  1.0  high  1.0
9  e  0.0   low  NaN
```

Comment: ah interesting. If 2 rows have the same `count`, how does this choose which row to keep?

Comment: @Simon it should be the first item, assuming sort_values performs as expected.

Answer (score 3):

This is what I am going to do, `drop_duplicates`, you can drop the `Notnullvalue` by using `.drop('Notnullvalue', 1)`

```
df['Notnullvalue'] = df.isnull().sum(1)
df.sort_values(['id', 'Notnullvalue']).drop_duplicates(['id'], keep='first')
Out[15]: 
  id   q1    q2   q3  Notnullvalue
0  a  1.0   low  NaN             1
4  b  0.0   low  0.0             0
5  c  NaN  high  0.0             1
6  d  1.0  high  1.0             0
9  e  0.0   low  NaN             1
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by @COLDSPEED, I have such a solution. Note `na_position='last'` is the default setting in `sort_values`.

```
df.sort_values(by=['q1','q2','q3'], na_position='last').groupby('id').head(1).sort_index()
```